# Current directory of Emacs in batch mode

Tags: start-up, directories

I run Emacs in batch mode to execute some scripting actions. I'd like to get paths of files relative to where Emacs got started in batch mode:

```
(file-relative-name (buffer-file-name) directory-where-emacs-was-started)
```

I do not know how to find out `directory-where-emacs-was-started`. `default-directory` does not work because it defaults to buffer file directory and `(default-value 'default-directory)` is `nil`.

How to find out what I'm looking for?

Edit: clarification, I need as elisp variable the value that `pwd` will print just before running Emacs in shell invocation like this:

```
pwd && emacs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `command-line-default-directory`, it is intended when using Emacs in batch mode, or when processing command line options:

> Default directory to use for command line arguments.
>   This is normally copied from `default-directory' when Emacs starts.

It retains its value throughout the session.

Answer (score 0):

If by "directory-where-emacs-was-started" you mean the directory where Emacs is located, then it is the value of this variable: **`invocation-directory`**:

> The directory in which the Emacs executable was found, to run it.
>   The value is nil if that directory's name is not known.

Depending on what you mean, you might also want to look at `exec-directory` or even the value of `default-directory` immediately after Emacs starts.

Comment: Neither `invocation-directory` nor `exec-directory` are what I'm looking for. Question clarified.

Comment: Your clarification confirms that what you want is "*the value of `default-directory` immediately after Emacs starts.*"

Comment: @Drew, which isn't what `invocation-directory` contains. It contains the directory of the Emacs binary, not the original current directory of the user.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Yes, of course. My answer said clearly "**IF**" what you mean is the directory where Emacs is located..." And the answer includes `exec-directory` and `default-directory`, "*depending on what you [OP] mean*". OP's clarification of the question shows that what was meant/requested is "*`default-directory` immediately after Emacs starts*".

Comment: @Drew -- Ah, I interpreted your comment (see "Your clarification...") that you still thought your answer was valid after the clarification.